# Changing slider image on mouseover of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I need advice on the following issue:

We are using wordpress as backend for a website and a theme that comes with a slider. I use that slider with some css to let divs slide up and show hidden content on mouseover (divs are displayed in front of a background image). This works great so far after searching for it here in stackoverflow.

What I would need now is a functionality that changes the image of the slider on mouseover of a div that is inside the slider-div.

HTML looks like this (extremely simplified):

```
<div class="ls-wp-fullwidth-container" style="height: 692px;">
<div class="ls-wp-fullwidth-helper" style="height: 692px; width: 1383px; left: 0px;">
    <div id="layerslider_3" class="ls-wp-container ls-container ls-fullwidth" style="margin: 0px auto; visibility: visible; width: 1383px; height: 691.5px;">
        <div class="ls-webkit-hack">
        </div>
        <div class="ls-inner" style="width: 1383px; height: 692px;">
            <div class="ls-layer ls-active" style="left: auto; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: auto; width: 1383px; height: 692px; display: none; visibility: visible;">
                <img src="http://bauer-bauer.at.w0126e5a.kasserver.com/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Siebdruck-Werkstatt-Winterthur-Zürich.jpg" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background" style="padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; width: 1660px; height: 922px; margin-left: -830px; margin-top: -461px;">
                <div class="ls-s-1 Highlight1" style="position: absolute; color: rgb(0, 111, 0); border-radius: 20px; white-space: nowrap; opacity: 1; transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1); display: block; visibility: visible; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; width: 253.55px; height: auto; font-size: 23.05px; line-height: 23.05px; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; left: 138.3px; top: 507.1px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"> 
                    <div id="parent">
                        <center>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <h1><a href="./?page_id=18">Siebdruck</a></h1>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Content</li>
                            </ul>
                        </center>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div id="hover-content">
                            <center>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Content shown on hover</li>
                                </ul>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do now is to change the image within the
`<div class="ls-layer ls-active>
<img src="...">
</div>"`

I figured out this would only be possible by using javascript so I tried the following:

Using this code in a header file:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("parent");
elem.addEventListener("mouseover",mouseOver);
elem.addEventListener("mouseout",mouseOut);
function mouseOver() {
document.getElementByClassName("ls-layer ls- active").style.backgroundImage="url(http://bauer-bauer.at.w0126e5a.kasserver.com/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/slider_stockfoto_3.jpg)";
}

function mouseOut() {
document.getElementByClassName("ls-layer ls-active").style.backgroundImage = "url(http://bauer-bauer.at.w0126e5a.kasserver.com/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Siebdruck-Werkstatt-Winterthur-Z%C3%BCrich.jpg)";
}
```

Didn't work, so I tried this:

```
function MouseIn() {
document.getElementByClassName("ls-layer ls-active").style.backgroundImage = "url(img/http://bauer-bauer.at.w0126e5a.kasserver.com/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/slider_stockfoto_3.jpg) no-repeat";
}
function MouseOut() {
document.getElementByClassName("ls-layer ls-active").style.backgroundImage = "url(img/http://bauer-bauer.at.w0126e5a.kasserver.com/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Siebdruck-Werkstatt-Winterthur-Z%C3%BCrich.jpg) no-repeat";
}
```

Didn't work as well, so I messed around with names and ids but couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong.

So, long story short: Is it possible to change the image within the structure stated above (`<div class="ls-layer ls-active><img src="..."></div>"`) when hovering `<div id="parent"></div>`? And if so, what am I obviously doing wrong?

As mentioned before, transitions created using css are working perfectly fine...

I hope you can help me, I'm growing more and more desperate about this.

Comment: `getElementByClassName()` gets a list of elements so you would have to select the specific one you want in the list.

Comment: I tried to get that list of elements (which is currently exactly one) and change the source of the image to a different one on hovering a div with the id "parent". I changed the code above so it looks like this now: `function changebg() {
 var el = document.getElementsByClassName("ls-bg");
 el.src = "url(/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/slider_stockfoto_3.jpg)";
};` it doesn't do anything though. No errors, no action. The only attributes of the image are src, alt, class, style... @Press

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
$("#parent").on({
 "mouseover" : function() {
     $( ".ls-bg" ).attr( "src", "http://placehold.it/350x150" );    
  },
  "mouseout" : function() {
    $( ".ls-bg" ).attr( "src", "http://placehold.it/950x150" );
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/950x150" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background">
</div>
```

**UPDATE ---**
Looking at your question I modified my code. I think this is what you want:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vdyqooqg/)

Comment: It looks promising and actually works how I want it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdyqooqg/5/) It doesn't work on the actual website though, so I guess it gets interrupted by another script or ignored entirely. If you want to take a look at the website itself, I can provide the link either by posting here or sending you a pm.

Comment: Yes you can post the link overhere or if you do not want to do that send me a pm. @JaroquinAzharael

Comment: [website link](http://bauer-bauer.at.w0126e5a.kasserver.com/wordpress/wordpress/) Maybe you can find something I'm missing out, it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry for asking but where can I see the element that does not work, on your website? @JaroquinAzharael

Comment: There are 4 divs that slide up when you hover (Offsetdruck, Tampondruck, Digitaldruck, Siebdruck) - the image they are layered upon should change when you hover those divs but it doesn't work. If you inspect the website using developer tools from a browser it is inside a "wrap all"-div... the structure is rather complicated. If you need further information on the structure I can send you an excerpt of it. I guess I had less issues if the structure was less complicated

Comment: oke found it! And where is the javascript code located? how is the file named? @JaroquinAzharael

Comment: The file is called changebgimage.js and is located in a subdirectory. I use a relative path to it: ./js/changebgimage.js I still feel like I'm missing something... from what I read the code should apply the function "onmouseover" to the #parent-element... @Pierezzz

Comment: The file is not being loaded! The website can not find it. If you look in your console window of firebug or google chrome developer. You will get the following message: http://bauer-bauer.at.w0126e5a.kasserver.com/wordpress/wordpress/js/changebgimage.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) @JaroquinAzharael

Comment: I fixed the path but now it's telling me "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"?? you can find the file [here](http://bauer-bauer.at.w0126e5a.kasserver.com/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/themes/enfold/js/changebgimage.js) @Pierezzz

Comment: Try to change: `$` into `jQuery` @JaroquinAzharael

Comment: I changed it and it doesn't show any error but it also doesn't do anything. I tried a different way of adding the function like this: `function changebg() {
 var el = document.getElementsByClassName("ls-bg").src;
 el = "http://bauer-bauer.at.w0126e5a.kasserver.com/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/slider_stockfoto_3.jpg";
};` and let this execute "onmouseover". This actually works on the same level of the structure (if I hover 1 div the first one changed) but not a level above (the image itself). I think the script can't access .ls-bg @Pierezzz

Comment: It is hard for me to find out where the problem is due to the fact that I can not directly edit and try somethings out on your website. I should for example should add console.log items to the function to actually see if the mouseover/mouseout is working. Perhaps you can add them. Or somehow send me the code and I will try to fix it for you locally. @JaroquinAzharael

Comment: BTW, try to add this to your code: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){// code});` I think your code is not loaded because it is not triggered. @JaroquinAzharael

Comment: What you are basically saying is that I'm supposed to wrap the function itself within `jQuery(document).ready(function($){// code});`? So the function I want to call would be placed where "// code" is right now? @Pierezzz

Comment: Yep, so it would look like this: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ jQuery("#parent").on({ "mouseover" : function() { jQuery( ".ls-bg" ).attr( "src", "http://placehold.it/350x150" ); }, "mouseout" : function() { jQuery( ".ls-bg" ).attr( "src", "http://placehold.it/950x150" ); } }); });`